# positioning a pair of chars(*) center instead of left

Tags: c#, for-loop, char

So i am struggling with a console application. It is required the line of chars to form a tree like pattern instead of right wing triangle. Like this(3):

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

so far i have this:

```
int rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
 {
            for(int x = 1; x <= i; x++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `PadLeft` function. It adds spaces to your string on the left side, so you can position it correctly. Also, you need to multiply the amount of rows by 2 and increase the step size by 1. You'll get the following code:

```
int rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) * 2;

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i += 2) {
  Console.Write( "".PadLeft( (rows - i) / 2) );
  for(int x = 1; x <= i; x++) {
    Console.Write("*");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Also, if you really want to make your triangle look like this, you might need to remove this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

... and change it to this:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

(This will remove the unnessecary newline, `WriteLine` already prints a newline).